# When Installing vending and gms apk files using adb command I face the errors

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

When Installing vending and gms apk files using adb command I face below errors, what is the meaning of errors and what is the solution of these errors?

[image]

In emulator google map program is work properly without any errors but maps are not shown in emulator.

My Program and google play services Specification :
I am doing Program in Android Platform 4.2.2 and emulator API Level v-17.
I am installing google play services by SDK Manager.

Also I am trying to uninstall these things by command prompt but message are shown in command prompt is "Failure".

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, there is an older version of your application on the Emulator/Device, which was signed with another key (or developer key). That's causing the `INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATE`-problem.

The solution here is to deinstall the application on the Device/Emulator and to re-install it then with the new key.